# Did they ever consider having children in Passengers?

Tags: passengers

SPOILERS FOLLOW!

In the film *Passengers*,

> Jim and Aurora make a life for themselves together aboard the starship, which presumably lasts for decades.

When the crew wake up during the final approach to Homestead II, it looks like they discover

> a greatly changed ship, and Aurora's memoirs, but no sign of any living people.

**Did Jim and Aurora ever consider having children together? If not, why not?**

As well as continuing not only their genetic line but also their way of living aboard the starship, this would have enabled them to still have loving company in the event that one of them died before the other. Multiple children could have kept each other company after both their parents were gone; nobody would ever have had to live entirely alone as Jim did at the start. Some of them might even have lived long enough to see Homestead II. The advantages seem to be many and the disadvantages none - and yet we see no sign that this ever happened, not even decades later.

Comment: For the record, it's not clear if the ship is set up to be generational. There are evidently supplies for 5000+ people for 4 months (1733 years). Assuming they had three children, and those three children had three children and grandchildren each (27 in total, plus the 2 progenitors), by the time the ship arrived at its destination in 89 years, there would be insufficient food for the passengers.

Comment: There were supplies for the colony onboard, too. Assuming they limited it to 2 children each, it’s just 10 people. Growing food, there should be enough food.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ending of the film was left *[intentionally vague](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbiguousEnding)* by the film's director, Morten Tyldum. In short, he's happy for you to imagine that they went on to have kids, but only if ***you*** want to.

> We had a longer ending with Andy Garcia walking out of the elevator.
> 'Why is he in one shot?' Because it was two scenes that we shot with
> him, but we find out that by doing the ending a little shorter, it
> made people talk more about it. **I want to like, 'Did they have
> children? What happened?' It's good. Somebody will go like, 'Oh, I
> think I saw some children inside the house.' Somebody goes like,
> 'Wait, if you saw that, then there probably is!' 'How was their life?'**
>
> But they both get to do what they set off to do. She set off to write
> a story. She thought it was different story. She had to, instead of
> looking outward, she had to look inward... Which I think is amazing,
> and he build his house, and was able to live in it... So, in many
> ways, **they completed what they needed, and the rest I want people to
> imagine and talk about and it should be up to them.**
>
> <sub><sup>['Passengers' director defends the movie's controversial ending](http://uk.businessinsider.com/passengers-director-defends-ending-2016-12)</sup></sub>

---

You may wish to note that in the film's [original script](http://www.indiewire.com/2016/12/passengers-space-romance-jennifer-lawrence-chris-pratt-sony-black-list-1201761058/), the ending was far less ambiguous. **They had kids and even made use of artificially inseminated sperm along the way**.

> The ship’s hull is scorched and abraded from its cosmic crossing. But
> the lights shine, the engines throb, the landing gear receive the
> weight of the ship.
>
> **The starship’s gangway lowers. The doors open. CHILDREN run down the
> gangway. Children of all ages, of all races. Twenty of them, thirty.
> They point at the sun, at the clouds, laughing, wide-eyed in wonder.**
>
> We move up the gangway, through the disembarking passengers. Behind
> the children: Teenagers. Adults in smaller numbers as they grow older.
> Finally a handful of gray-haired elders.
>
> ...
>
> At the aft end of the Concourse, a high wall. Here a long list of
> dates is inscribed. The last date is the ship’s landfall on Homestead
> II; the first, Jim’s awakening. **In between: an accelerating tally of
> births, deaths, marriages, catastrophes and achievements**...a century
> of shipboard life.

Which was a necessity because they'd

> accidentally vented all 5000 of the other passengers into space.

and no, I'm not joking. That's what actually happened. Seriously.

Comment: Very interesting - danke. (Need a warning for that TV Tropes link though...)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I think the spoiler (from the original script) needs a bigger warning :-)

Comment: Children.... of all races? From two people?!

Comment: I loved this movie. I really did. Naysayers be damned. But I will admit that the notion of a company whose motivation is purely profit, whose profit derives from sending ships back and forth on a _120-year voyage_, really stretched credibility for me. How could any executive in that firm possibly have a vested interest in what they were doing? It's interesting because this will supposedly be how our businesses work in a few whatever years.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - They used fertilised sperm samples to breed biologically unrelated partners for their children, neatly dealing with the whole "*Adam and Eve Vs inbreeding*" problem (but not the ick factor).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - In the original script, it's mentioned that each voyage is separated by about 30 years. That's a plausible amount of time for a company to make long-term investments. Given that 5000 people are evidently willing to freeze themselves and give up their lives to go live on farms, it's hardly surprising that back on Earth there would be 30,000 people willing to help them. Note that it's Aurora (a deeply cynical hack) who accuses them to doing this only for the profit motive

Comment: I've just [made use of your answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/66278/27759) on another site - I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's absolutely fine. I have zero interest in that site. A quick glance suggests that you're not the only one making use of my answers, albeit the only one crediting me for the research.

Comment: Hm..I'm going to have to re-watch.  I could've sworn the version I watched made reference to "their descendants" in the end narration. Granted, that was ondemand rather than in theaters so perhaps I got an extended cut.

Comment: @Paul - This is the script for the ending; http://chillnflix.to/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Passengers.2016.1080p.KORSUB.HDRip_.x264.AAC2_.0-STUTTERSHIT.vtt

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another thing should be considered.

The protagonist was exposed to the reactor plasma or whatever was vented from the reactor. While we cannot be sure what was the principle of the reactor function we can suppose that he had received an (un)healthly dose of radiation. True, the autodoc revived him and put him back to health, but we cannot be sure about long term effects of his exposure. He could have been sterilized or his genetic material  could have been damaged to the extent that procreation would be unadvisable.

Comment: This is certainly a possibility, but it's very speculative.

Comment: The bad news is yes if there is sufficient radiation he will be sterile. The good news its only temporary. Yes when faced with sufficient radiation men can be sterile as well as the semen will be mutated. Yet, the wonders of life and human strength continues as after a certain amount of time if no further radiation is experienced the semen production and normality will continue, YAY! Men are always producing new sperm. If it was the woman then that would a different story all together. Women are born with all the eggs they will ever use and left overs to spare. We are talking millions.